# Is it possible to change country location?

Tags: support, edits, profile-page, location

I'm soon moving to a different country and am wondering if it is possible to change the country details in Stack Exchange, if so, how? The option doesn't seem to appear on my profile

Comment: Don't you see it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current Under the display name, it says location for me.

Comment: @MarkKirby thanks, sorry, for some reason I couldn't find out how to navigate to that spot.

Comment: No problem, the profile can be confusing. I posted this as an answer, please accept it to show your isue was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

You can change your location in your profile.

From your profile choose the Edit profile and settings tab

[image]

You can see the location option in the public information section.

Alternatively just click this [multi user link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current).